# Add many rows with incrementing values. (Fill down?)

Tags: mysql, bulkinsert

I want to add 10,000 rows to a MySQL table. The table has a field, let's call it "Number", that needs to increment from 540000 to 549999.

This is just something that needs to run once, so performance is not critical. Is there a MySQL command that will do this, or do I need to write a script to call 10,000 insert statements?

Comment: Do you need the 10,000 rows or do you just want to fast-forward the auto_increment number?

Comment: @macek: I need the 10,000 rows.

Comment: are you using a server side language like PHP or do you need a solution completely in mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a script with 10,000 insert statements.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have those 10,000 rows in a tab-delimited file, you can bulk load the data into your table and set the Number value incrementally like this:

```
set @number = (540000 - 1);

load data infile '/tmp/your_data.txt' 
ignore into table your_table 
(column_1,...,column_n) 
set Number = (@number := @number + 1);
```